# Whenever I use any material ui icon, I am getting this error. And when I remove the material ui icon from my code, the error disappears

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMcfb.png)Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-cal

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "./AddKeywordsPage.css";
import './AddedKeywords';
import AddedKeywords from './AddedKeywords';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

import { db } from '../../firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import FeedCreated from '../LeftMenuBar/FeedCreated';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectUser } from '../features/userSlice';

function AddKeywordsPage({ toggle }) {

    const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState([]);
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const [feedInput, setFeedInput] = useState('');

    const history = useHistory();

    const user = useSelector(selectUser);

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     db.collection('keywords').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
    //         setKeywords(
    //             snapshot.docs.map((doc) => (
    //                 {
    //                     id: doc.id,
    //                     data: doc.data()
    //                 }
    //             ))
    //         ))
    // }, [])
    
    useEffect(() => {

        db.collection('keywords').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
            setKeywords(
                snapshot.docs.map((doc) => (
                    {
                        id: doc.id,
                        data: doc.data()
                    }
                ))
            ))
    }, [])

    const addKeywordTag = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();

        db.collection('keywords').add({
            keyword: input,
            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        });

        setInput("");
    };

        const addFeed = (eve) => {
            eve.preventDefault();

            db.collection('feeds').add({
                feed: feedInput,
                timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            });

            console.log(setFeedInput);
            setFeedInput("");
            setKeywords([]);
            alert("Feed added successfully");
        }

    return (
        <div className="addkeywordspage_main">

        
        <div className="addkeywordspage">
        <div>
            <p className="addkeywordspage_keywords">Create Feed</p>
            <div className="addkeywordspage_feed">
            <TextField
                        value={feedInput}
                        onChange={eve => setFeedInput(eve.target.value)}
                        style={{ width: '300px'}}
                        id="outlined-basic"
                        label="Add Feed Name"
                        variant="outlined"
                        InputLabelProps={{style: {fontSize: 15}}}
                    />
            </div>

            <div className="addkeywordspage_flex">
                <div className="addkeywordspage_textfield">
                    
                    <TextField
                        value={input}
                        onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
                        style={{ width: '400px' }}
                        id="outlined-basic"
                        label="Add phrases"
                        variant="outlined"
                        InputLabelProps={{style: {fontSize: 15}}}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="addkeywordspage_button1">
                    <button onClick={addKeywordTag}>Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="over">
                {keywords.map(({ id, data: { keyword } }) => (
                    <AddedKeywords
                        id={id}
                        keyword={keyword}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>

        
                    <div className="add_feed_button">
                <button onClick={addFeed} >Add Feed</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddKeywordsPage;
```

l for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: Please add the code segment that you've used in the file.

Comment: can you share what you did so far? code snippet ? please follow stackoverflow question guidelines How to Ask? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask